# Error when querying for specific field inside an array inside a document in Firebase V9

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I posted a question earlier about how to query for a specific value inside an array. I was told that there was a similar question already asked. I have looked at the solution for that question however i am getting an error. This is my code currently to check to see if the field mal_id inside the favourites array contains an id passed by me.

```
const docRef = collection(db, 'users')
const q = query(docRef, where('favourites', 'array-contains', {mal_id: id}))
```

I then attached an onSnapshot method to see if the data exists which is like this

```
onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
    if(snapshot.data()){
      console.log(true)
    }
    else{
      console.log(false)
    }
  })
```

But i get an error saying snapshot.data is not a function. idk if you are not supposed to use an onSnapshot method on this kind of query or my code is wrong. I have attached a picture of my database structure. Thanks.

*********Edit********
So, i have changed my data structure. Now i am creating a new field called animeID and then storing the id into it. I then do the array contains onto that but the snapshot still gives me the same error. Here is the updated code along with a new picture of my database structure.

```
const docRef = collection(db, 'users')
  const q = query(docRef, where('animeID', 'array-contains', `mal_id: ${id}`))
  onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
    if(snapshot.data()){
      console.log(true)
    }
    else{
      console.log(false)
    }
  })
```

[Updated firestore structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fTV2.png)

Comment: That query will not find the document you're showing here.  In fact, Firestore does not have the ability to find nested object fields within an array field.  The only way you can filter on an array field is to provide the entire contents of the array item in your query.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Doug commented, Firestore's `array-contains` operator checks for equivalence between the value you supply and an entire array item. It can't find a subset of an item.

The common workaround is to add an additional field to your document with just the `mal_id` values you want query on. So something like:

```
Favourites_mal_ids: [21]
```

And then you can perform an `array-contains` on *that* field.

Comment: Hi, i have edited the my question to implement your suggestion but i still have problems.

Comment: The field you now have is **not** an array, so `array-contains` makes no sense. If you have a field with a single value, you can use `==`.

Comment: Hi, after realising that my animeID filed was indeed not an array i corrected it and now it is working. Thank you for the help.